# Is there any way to retrieve the UUID of an iPhone using Titanium?

Tags: iphone, titanium, uuid

The API documentations says that **Titanium.Platform.getId()** returns the UDID (unique device ID) for android but for iOS this is a unique identifier for a particular installation of the application. It also says that Apple has restricted the access to UUID.

However, if I need to retrieve a unique device ID for an iPhone, is there any way to do it? Or is it not possible at all?

Comment: You mean UDID and no, there isn't. There used to be but apple stopped it. You can get other IDs though like "IDForVendor" or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get any device unique identifiers in iOS 7 and up, Apple has restricted this due to privacy concerns. The trick to use the MAC address is also no longer working.

You options are the identifier for vender (the one `Titanium.Platform.getId()` returns). 
This one is unique for the device as long as there is app on the device from the same developer.

Another option is to create a unique identifier and save it in the keychain, this way it will be saved there until the user full wipes it's iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Check [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/) for some more information.

Comment: I've answered the question. The link is only additional information. I'm posting the link because some people writes really well their articles so they deserves to share with their work and not only copy it.